# Call JAVA applet method from JavaScript, IE/FF object/embed issue

Tags: java, javascript, dom, browser, applet

I'm using JavaScript to access methods inside a JAVA applet.

The applet is embedded into the HTML page this way:

```
<object
class="cn" id="testapplet-object" 
        classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93"
        width="300" height="300"
        codebase="http://java.sun.com/update/1.6.0/jinstall-6u30-windows-i586.cab#Version=1,6,0,0">
  <param name="archive" value="TestCom.jar" />
  <param name="code" value="TestCom.class" />
  <param name="scriptable" value="true" />
  <param name="mayscript" value="mayscript" />
  <embed class="cn" id="testapplet-embed"
         type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.6"
         width="300" height="300" 
         archive="TestCom.jar"
         code="TestCom.class" 
         pluginspage="http://java.com/download/"
         myParam="My Param Value",
         mayscript="mayscript" />
  </embed>
</object>
```

Under this applet there is a button and the code related to the button is the following:

```
  var applet = document.getElementById("testapplet-object");
  var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

  btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
    applet.callAppletMethod();
  });
```

Problem is: this code only works in IE. To make it work in Firefox I must pass "testapplet-embed" to getElementById (but then it won't work in IE).

Is there any crossbrowser way to declare my applet variable?

Comment: What about using both as a workaround?

Comment: Have you tried using JSObject?

Comment: First question: I can't put the same id, the id should be unique. Second question: I'm using JSObject but the applet code is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use deployJava.js.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html

```
var attributes = {
    id:'testapplet',
    archive:"TestCom.jar",
    code:"TestCom" 
    code:'jstojava.MathApplet',
    width:300, height:300
};
var parameters = {} ;
deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6');
```

Comment: I tried this yesterday, but for some reason it doesn't work because it can't find "TestCom" or "TestCom.class", that none removed  :-)